# Searching multiple models with pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search

I am trying to implement a full text search in my rails app. I am using PostgreSQL as a database, therefore, using PostgreSQL's full text search capabilities. I have two models Users and Scoreboards and I want to search through both models against specific columns to pull out records.

I am using pg_search gem for full text search, I read the multisearch documentation and implemented everything successfully. I have created the pg_search_documents table. The code is given below.

**Scoreboard Model**

```
include PgSearch
   multisearchable :against => [:name_of_organization, :name_of_activity, :name_of_scoreboard]
```

**User Model**

```
include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => :name
```

**Controller Code**

```
 def index
   @pg_search_documents = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:search])
 end
```

The search works when I run the code `<%= pg_search.searchable %>` in the view. This returns both the user and scoreboard OBJECTS when each one of them are searched.

**View code**

```
<% @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search| %>
        <%= pg_search.searchable.name %>
        <%= pg_search.searchable.name_of_organization %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I try to run the view code given above and search for a name, I will get the following error,

```
undefined method `name_of_scoreboard' for #<User:0x007fa44ad18cd8>.
```

I get a similar error when I try to search for the name_of_scoreboard,

```
`undefined method `name' for #<Scoreboard:0x00000006fa3560>.`
```

If I use the following code in my view, `<%= @pg_search_documents.searchable.id %>`, the id's for both the user and scoreboard show up. This means that I can only search against columns that are common in the two models.

If I try to search for two different columns such as **name and name_of_scoreboard**, I get the two errors I mentioned above. I am able to search between two different models but I am not able to display the results from the view. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or maybe I am missing something important. I am really not sure. I have tried to keep it brief and tried to include relevant information. If any specific code is required, please let me know. As always, Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're mixing up "searching for" and displaying a column from the results of - It looks like your code is actually searching across different fields in multiple models. That search then returns an array of "documents" which point to the matching objects.  The issue you're having is that you're trying to display the name of an object that doesn't have a name. I think something like the following is what you're going for.

```
<% @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search| %>
  <% if pg_search.searchable.respond_to?(:name) %>
    <%= pg_search.searchable.name %>
  <% else %>
    <%= pg_search.searchable.name_of_organization %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That will display the name if the result object has a name (ie - if its a user) and otherwise the organization name (if its a scoreboard).  Note, this isn't a great solution since it's now introducing logic into your view but it explains the issue.

Comment: @ Tom Walpole Thank you so much, this definitely works. I understand the if and else statement. However, do you mind explaining the code <% if pg_search.searchable.respond_to?(:name) %>. Although, I can make sense of the code by reading it. I don't fully understand it. Also, what would be the best place to put logic relating to the view. I usually put the if and else statements in the view.

Comment: That code just sees if the object has a 'name' method - since the scoreboard object doesn't it will only match to users.  It's a little more flexible than saying   `if pg_search.searchable.is_a? User`  since if you added other objects to the results with a name method it would just keep working (see duck typing).  For removing logic from views read up on the decorator pattern, or you could just render a partial for each of the results, which would hide the logic in the partial rendering since it will use a different partial for each type of result object - render @pg_search_documents.to_a

Comment: @ Tom Walpole Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I really appreciate the help. Thanks once again!!