# Pg_search migration not add column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I have two models

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:title, :content]
```

...

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:title, :content]
```

I run command

```
rails g pg_search:migration:multisearch
```

Its generate this migration

```
class CreatePgSearchDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    say_with_time("Creating table for pg_search multisearch") do
      create_table :pg_search_documents do |t|

        t.text :content
        t.belongs_to :searchable, :polymorphic => true, :index => true
        t.timestamps null: false
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    say_with_time("Dropping table for pg_search multisearch") do
      drop_table :pg_search_documents
    end
  end
end
```

Its not add column **title**. Why so?

**Update**. Pg_Search concatenate column title and content in one column - content. I dont understand why.

**Rails** 5.0.2

**Ruby** ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1):

`pg_search` is concatenating the different columns into one to simplify the use of `ts_vector`.

If you have different column weighting words and searching is more complicated as you have to get everything sync and properly ordered at the end of the process.

I would recommend reading the following https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/86 if you are interested into weighting keywords (a solution is proposed near the end) and [Searching multiple models with pg_search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914097/searching-multiple-models-with-pg-search)